# Stop referencing object with vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I know that the default behaviour of a object when we create new atributes for the same instance is that it reference the old, changing the properties.

I have something like this on my vue data:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            paragraph: {
                text: "",
                fontSize: 14,
                key: "Paragraph",
                align: "left"
            }

        }
    },
    methods: {
        addParagraph() {
            this.$set(this.paragraph, 'key', this.paragraph.key);
            this.$set(this.paragraph, 'text', this.paragraph.text);
            this.$set(this.paragraph, 'fontSize', this.paragraph.fontSize);
            this.$set(this.paragraph, 'align', this.paragraph.align);
            this.$store.commit("appendToDocument", this.paragraph)
        },
        alignment(option) {
            this.paragraph.align = option;
        }
    }
```

everytime i click a button the data inside the paragraph changes and i want to pas the data to vuex store to add it to a json, so i can have a tree of paragraphs, the problem is, that everttime i create a new paragrapg it changes the values of my other paragraphs created before, is there a way to change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Potray answer is good. But it can be even shorter if you are using Babel with stage-3 (spread operator). Then you can copy all properties with that syntax

```
addParagraph() {
    this.$store.commit("appendToDocument", { ...this.paragraph })
},
```

Comment: what does the ... mean?

Comment: here you find nice examples https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread/blob/master/Spread.md

3 dots operator in that case means:

create new object A then copy all properties from object B and then paste add them to abject A.

Basically in your case { ...this.paragraph } do exactly what @potray code.
You may be familiar with spread/rest operator for arrays. it landed in ES2015. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator. 
Spread/rest for objects is almost a standard

Comment: just a think, what happens to the reference, id doesn't care? i like yout solution im curious :D

Comment: value types are copied ... so there is no reference between source object and target object

Comment: but if your property in source object is an object then target and source point to same place

Comment: you can easily experiment with that in ChromeBrowser console. Spread operator for objects is implemented there

Comment: gist with example https://gist.github.com/ppasieka/981f20f31bec43b4623f46d18603fa61#file-gistfile1-txt

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 addParagraph() {
        var paragraph = {
           key: this.paragraph.key,
           text: this.paragraph.text,
           fontSize: this.paragraph.fontSize,
           align: this.paragraph.alignkey,
        }
        this.$store.commit("appendToDocument", paragraph)
    },
```

Comment: not my favourite solution since i need to write all again, but it works :D, thank you !!